# Entity Framework, How to generate a random int number that doesn't exist in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to generate a random int number that doesn't exist in database to avoid duplicate data. in other words i need to check in database if the code doesn't exist database before generating the generated code.

This is how my Entity looks like:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

}
```

and here is the way i generate the code:

```
        User user new User();
        Random random = new Random();
        user.Code = random.Next().ToString();
```

Comment: why are you doing this yourself and why aren't you using unique id's generated and managed by sql-server? if you want something random, use a [uniqueidentifier/guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)

Comment: You could always stick a `[Key]` attribute above the `Id` property.

Comment: @Tanner.. I don't need an id, i just need to generate a number that doesn't exist in database .. How to check if the number in database and if the number already in database how to generate another one

Comment: @MikeEason... I don't need an id, i just need to generate a number that doesn't exist in database .. How to check if the number in database and if the number already in database how to generate another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tanner asks, why do you need this functionality?

It would help us direct you to the best solution.

There are some reasonable use cases (such as performance) where you don't want a round trip to the database to get the Id of your entity.

That said in most cases it's best to let the database handle this for you, unless you have a compelling reason not to.

To answer you question there are two ways of solving this problem.

A) Use a GUID instead. They are designed to be unique and you can assign one to your entity to identify it both before and after you commit your entity. You may want to still use an int as your primary key due to performance issues around using GUIDS for this purpose.

B) Use a HiLo key generation strategy. This will allow you to assign ids before saving down you entities. This feature is only available in the .NET Core version of Entity Framework (and nHibernate).

http://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-hilo-to-generate-keys-with-entity-framework-core/
https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/Key-Generation-Strategies-in-Entity-Framework-7